# print lowest value in hash of hashes

Tags: perl, hash

I am experiencing issues completing a simple task. I have the following hash of hashes:

```
%hash = (
personA => {
    2017   => 1,
    2018   => 2,
},
personB => {
    2015   => 4,
    2013   => 28,
    2014   => 1, .
},
personC => {
    2013   => 3,
    2011   => 2,
    2012   => 45,
},
);
```

I am trying to print out the earliest year for each person, e.g. something like:

personA 2017

personB 2013

personC 2011

It seems that `List::Util` is the best tool for this, but I cannot find an example to adapt for my data. I am having trouble because the solutions I have found are trying to sort/print the first level of the hash (i.e., `personA`, etc.), as opposed to the years.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my %hash;
my $hash; 

%hash = (
personA => {
    2017   => 1,
    2018   => 2,
},
personB => {
    2015   => 4,
    2013   => 28,
    2014   => 1,
},
personC => {
    2013   => 3,
    2011   => 2,
    2012   => 45,
},
);

use List::Util qw(min);
my $min = min keys %hash;
$hash = {$min => $hash->{$min}};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Loop through the people.  Then, dereference each person hash to get a list of the years:

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use List::Util qw(min);

my %people = (
personA => {
    2017   => 1,
    2018   => 2,
},
personB => {
    2015   => 4,
    2013   => 28,
    2014   => 1,
},
personC => {
    2013   => 3,
    2011   => 2,
    2012   => 45,
},
);

for my $person (sort keys %people) {
    my $min = min(keys %{ $people{$person} });
    print "$person $min\n";
}
```

Outputs:

```
personA 2017
personB 2013
personC 2011
```

Answer (score 3):

You can avoid using any module at all while keeping the simplicity.

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my %hash = (
    personA => {
        2017 => 1,
        2018 => 2,
    },
    personB => {
        2015 => 4,
        2013 => 28,
        2014 => 1,
    },
    personC => {
        2013 => 3,
        2011 => 2,
        2012 => 45,
    },
);

foreach my $person ( sort keys %hash ) {
    printf( "%s %d\n", $person, ( sort keys %{ $hash{$person} } )[0] );
}
```

*( sort keys %{ $hash{$person} } )[0]* - sorts the keys in a ascending order (which is by default) and then get the first one.

Comment: Probably rather `sort { $a <=> $b }` for the second sort. On this precise example, it doesn't change anything (and since the keys look like somewhat recent dates, it probably won't change anything with any data this program could run on), but comparing number with a string comparison doesn't sound like a good idea.